# Получить Process по имени окна с#

Tags: c#, windows, процесс

Есть ли способ получить Process по имени окна этого процесса?
Пример: в c++ есть функция FindWindow(), нужно нечто похожее в c#.

Process.GetProcessesByName("xxx"); ищет по имени процесса, а не по окна. Нужно нечто похожее, только ищущее по имени окна.
Буду крайне признателен, если поможете:D

Comment: Используйте функцию WinAPI через [PInvoke](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.findwindow).

Comment: Вы можете получить все процессы и через LINQ найти процесс, окошко которого содержит нужный текст. [Как получить процессы](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1013/how-to-retrieve-list-the-titles-and-process-id-of-all-the-opened-applications-in-the-taskbar-of-windows-with-csharp-in-winforms)

Comment: @KuzCode спс за идею, реализовал немного по другому, но ты сильно помог :D

Comment: @IvanAcoola так поделитесь в ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функции Win32 можно использовать в C#.

Можно импортировать функцию Win API:

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(IntPtr className, string windowName);
```

И вот так вызвать:

```cs
string windowName = "Название окна";
IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow(IntPtr.Zero, windowName);
if (hwnd != null)
{
    // здесь hwnd - указатель на дескриптор окна
    Console.WriteLine("Окно найдено");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Окно не найдено");
}
```

Дескриптор окна можно использовать с других функциях WinAPI, например `ShowWindow` и `SetForegroundWindow`.

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
```

```cs
ShowWindow(hwnd, 9);
SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static bool findapp()
    {
        var processesss = Process.GetProcessesByName("xxxx");
        if (processesss.Length <= 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < processesss.Length; i++)
            {
                if (processesss[i].MainWindowTitle == "WindowName")
                {
                    return true;
                }

            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```